# Working with lag in AndEngine game, Heap DDMS solution

Tags: java, android, eclipse, andengine

I am developing a game with andengine.

Throughtout my game i place sprites on the scene, i am using a pool to resuse sprites already allocated.

I notice a few freezes throughout my game.

i was told to look at the heap in the DDMS tool in eclipse.

Here is how mine looks, I dont really understand it. Is this bad or good? Could anyone tell me what some of these things mean?

[image: Heap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything special here. Sprites themselves don't take much memory (I'd say less than 500 bytes). What takes memory is the textures - but if you load them once in your game (`onLoadResources`) then the freezes are not related to memory issues.

What else could be the problem? Calling `System.gc` too often, for example. You should track these freezes and find where and when they occur.

Comment: What would you recommend as far as tracking the freezes?

Comment: First of all, *when* the freeze occurs. What happens before & after. After you find out these details you can go deeper and find the exact method, exact line and so on.

Comment: Do you think it would help to make textures as small as possible?

Comment: It might. But you should first investigate the relevant code.